# How python custom class differ from any other in-built object like list?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I m not sure my question title is correct but :

My problem is :

When I created a new class called **classA** and i did **deepcopy** to another name called **classB** and did **equality and identity test**:

Here is my first snippet: Creating class using `type`

```
>>> import copy
>>> classA = type('X', (object,), {})
>>> classB = copy.deepcopy(classA)
>>> classB is classA
True
>>> classB == classA
True
>>>
```

Second snippet: testing on class creating by using keywords 'class':

```
>>> class X(object): pass
...
>>> import copy
>>> Y = copy.deepcopy(X)
>>> Y is X
True
>>> Y == X
True
>>>
```

Third snippet: And when i do the same testing on list object:

```
>>> import copy
>>> objA = list()
>>> objB = copy.deepcopy(objA)
>>> objB == objA
True
>>> objB is objA
False
>>>
```

Why the first and remaining two are different ? Could someone please explain me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) behavior:

> This module does not copy types like module, method, stack trace, stack frame, file, socket, window, array, or any similar types. It does “copy” functions and classes (shallow and deeply), by returning the original object unchanged; this is compatible with the way these are treated by the pickle module.

As to why it was done that way, presumably it was because people don't have a lot of need for having multiple identical but distinct classes.